# DocuSign - how to get an envelopes custom fields

Tags: docusignapi

When I call "listCustomFields($account_id, $envelope_id) from EnvelopesApi, none of the custom fields are returned, instead I get:-

```
 "custom_fields" => DocuSign\eSign\Model\CustomFieldsEnvelope {#1138 ▼
    #container: array:2 [▼
      "list_custom_fields" => []
      "text_custom_fields" => array:1 [▼
        0 => DocuSign\eSign\Model\TextCustomField {#1139 ▼
          #container: array:7 [▼
            "configuration_type" => null
            "error_details" => null
            "field_id" => "10581307682"
            "name" => "templateUsageRestriction"
            "required" => "false"
            "show" => "false"
            "value" => "allOptions"
```

How can I get all the custom fields that have been used in this envelope and can I display what the fields were set to?

Cheers
Carl.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're trying to run [example 15](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Controllers/Examples/eSignature/EG015EnvelopeTabData.php#L93) as shown in the PHP launcher. You'll need to run this call for each envelope sent to retrieve the completed form data. I believe that listCustomFields is related to the metaData associated with the envelope and not necessarily the custom tabs data that is attached to documents within the envelope.  For instance, if you wished to attach a seal ID to an envelope or a specific name or identifier, you could use the listCustomFields to retrieve the attributes on that custom field for the envelope.

For php that boils down to the following:

```
    $config = new Configuration();
    $config->setHost($args['base_path']);
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);    
    $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
    $envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient)
    $results = $envelope_api->getFormData($args['account_id'], $args['envelope_id']);

    return $results;
```

Here is an [API reference link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeformdata/get/) for more information about this underlying call.

Comment: once again, thank you for help, this worked a treat, I've now managed to show what I think I need for this to display everything needed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're looking for Envelope Custom Fields?

If you're trying to pull form data that the signer interacts with, those are *tabs*, and you can do so with a [GetEnvelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/) call using `include=recipients,tabs`.

The eSignature API's vocabulary is a bit different than the DocuSign web console's. Here's some more info that may help you get started: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/

Comment: I use the folders api to get all the folders (Inbox/Sent items/Drafts/Deleted):- I then find all the envelopes in each folder (currently 4 in Sent items) by getting then with a listStatusChange (inc folderid), when I have an envelope I do a listRecipients with includeTabs set to true so I get their names and email addresses but am struggling to get the form data. Is there an API I should be using